# Why are named nested structure allowed?

Tags: c, struct

I stumbled upon a very strange feature of C: you can declare a named structure inside another structure provided that declare a member variable of that type at the same time:

```c
struct Robot_st {
    int pos_x;
    int pos_y;
    struct BatteryStatus_st { /* <- named struct */
        int capacity;
        int load;
    } battery;
};
```

The inner structure becomes then available outside the structure as any other type, rendering strange code like this perfectly valid:

```c
struct Robot_st my_robot = {2, 3, {200, 50}};
struct BatteryStatus_st battery_snapshot; /* <- use of inner struct */

memcpy(
    &battery_snapshot,
    &my_robot.battery,
    sizeof(struct BatteryStatus_st)
);

printf("robot position: %d,%d\n", my_robot.pos_x, my_robot.pos_y);
printf("battery load: %d%%\n", battery_snapshot.load);
```

Nesting unnamed structures feels right, because as you cannot access the type later, there is no confusion about the scope of the type. The above code is also not valid in C++, although the nested declaration is, because C++ understands it as a type in the namespace of the outer structure, so you need to access it using

```cpp
struct Robot_st::BatteryStatus_st battery_snapshot;
```

which, despite feeling strange to declare both a type and a member at the same time, makes more sense.

So why is this construct valid in C? Is there any history/reason behind? Is there a use case for such a construct? (Mine was a mistake that led to failures, thus the question.)

[Link to full working code](https://gist.github.com/Cilyan/3aea714fe005bc795bde).

Comment: There are times and places that nested classes or structures are useful.  They follow the same rules as other member variables, and can be declared public, protected or private.

Comment: Because that's how the grammar in the specification is defined? Declarations/definitions inside structures uses the same rules as other variable declarations/definitions.

Comment: Please don't tag questions both C and C++. This does not work the same way in the two languages. What you describe applies only to C, not to C++, and you already noticed that yourself too.

Comment: C doesn't have scope resolution like C++ does so the naming semantics is different

Comment: Why should it *not* be valid in C?  I'd be inclined to say that it's *poor form* to declare a tagged `struct` type inside another `struct` declaration and then use it outside, but there's nothing inherently inconsistent about it.  Declaration scope in C just isn't quite what you thought it was.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: True. It's maybe hard to explain, but this is the combination of both the possibility of declaring a type inside a struct and the fact that it *must* declare a member at the same time, that makes me feel that it *could* be illegal. A little bit like if `typedef int mytype myvar;` was legal.

Comment: @Cilyan, as long as you're bringing up typedefs, consider that `typedef struct mystruct { int member; } mytype;` *is* legal.  It declares both `struct mystruct` and `mytype`, with the latter being an alias for the former.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Agreed. Though it's still *type* creation. Not a mix. But maybe I'm too over-precise? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such constructs were allowed in C originally because structure names occupied a universe all their own which never had any sort of scoping rules applied to it [struct *member names* did too, by the way, which is why some of the structure types in older standard libraries have prefixes on their members].  Because some code exists which uses structure names in a fashion inconsistent with scoping, the standard could not be changed to prohibit such usage without breaking existing code.  While there are times when it's worthwhile to break existing code (e.g. to rid C of the abomination called `gets`) this really isn't one of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Some links would be super great also. After you mentioned it, I looked a some old code and found this in time.h: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=time/time.h;h=87b9ba1596871eb45452cc04cf061cd4de4cc743;hb=HEAD#l132 Do you think it's what you are talking about or is it just convention? The itimerspec below shows the same characteristics.

Comment: @Cilyan: The fields tm_sec, tm_min, etc. are the kind of naming I was talking about.

Comment: @Cilyan: Although I don't have a reference, my understanding is that the earliest versions of C would behave as though all structure types were members of the same union.  Given `struct timespec foo;`, saying `foo.tm_min` on a system where sizeof(int)==2 would access the third and fourth bytes of `foo`.  The compiler would have to know the size of `foo` to know where the next variable should be allocated, but beyond that all it would know or care about was that `foo` was "some kind of structure".  Fortunately compilers have grown up a bit since then.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other two answers, here is a real usecase that calls for such a named inner struct:

```
struct LinkedList {
    //data members stored once per list
    struct LinkedListNode {
        //data members for each entry of the list
        struct LinkedListNode *next;
    } *head, *tail;
};
```

Its hard to write a more concise definition for the structure of a linked list.

An unnamed inner struct won't do: The code that inserts something into the linked list will likely have to declare local variables with node pointers. And there is no point in declaring the node structure outside of the linked list structure.

Comment: Ah! Nice one. I usually used a prototype instead (`struct LinkedListNode; struct LinkedListNode { ... };` and thought that was the only valid way to do. So yeah, it seems a valid useful usecase to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say I have this structure:

```
struct OuterStruct
{
    int a;
    struct InnerStruct
    {
        int i;
        int j;
    } b;
} s;
```

Now I can access `s.a`, and I can even save it in a variable, to better handle it, pass it to functions, ...

```
int sa = s.a;
```

Well, now I want to do the same with `s.b`, and to do so I need `InnerStruct` to have a name!

```
???? sb = s.b;   // here I have to use InnerStruct, otherwise sb would have no valid type!
```

The alternative would be to declare `InnerStruct` outside of `OuterStruct`, and then putting an instance of it inside as member of `OuterStruct`. But this would hide the fact that `InnerStruct` belongs to `OuterStruct`, making your intent less clear.

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? Please, provide some feedback, so that I can improve.

Comment: An unnamed structure is a one where the *type* doesn't have a name, not the variable. That's probably why you got downvoted? In your example, this means remove the identifier `InnerStruct`, not `b`.

Comment: @Cilyan Maybe my answer is not clear. What I mean is that if you remove `InnerStruct` (making in unnamed) then you have nothing to put in the question marks. That's why you need that name.

Comment: OK, understood. However, this is precisely a case where I find this construct wrong. For such a case, it is clear (well, to me at least :) ) that the type should be declared separately, because it represents an entity of its own.

Comment: @Cilyan I don't agree with you, I often find more logical to nest some declarations, to show the binding within them. But I understand that **sometimes** the choice between the two approaches is just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is legal in C:

```
struct BatteryStatus_st {
    int capacity;
    int load;
};

struct Robot_st {
    int pos_x;
    int pos_y;
    struct BatteryStatus_st battery;
};
```

and, as you pointed out, it is effectively identical to the code you posted (since C doesn't have the namespace/scoping rules introduced in C++).

If moving the "inner" type inside doesn't change anything, but may sometimes clarify intent, it would seem odd to prohibit it.

Comment: My point was, if it is equivalent, why not enforce it? That is to say, in your code above, it's easy to see that `struct BatteryStatus_st` is a type that can be use elsewhere in the code, whether in my example, it is not.